# Composer very slow on one computer, no problem on others

Tags: composer-php, ubuntu-18.04

Been having issues on a particular Linux machine with the composer package manager. On this particular machine, it seems it can't download anything from repo.packagist.org/p. The download speeds I get are 10~15KB/s
[image]

Ubuntu 18.04
Composer 1.7.3
PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a mirror issue (this machine not selecting different, if that's even a function)

The following solves it temporary:

```
composer config repositories.packagist.org composer https://repo-eu-uk-1.packagist.org
```

Comment: For someone stumbling upon this more background information can be found at https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7782#issuecomment-438585301.